# Powershell update a variable using another variable reference

Tags: powershell, variables, powershell-2.0

I'm trying to concatenate a variable reference inside another string but it keeps showing wrong values.

Basically I intend to update variable $arq value acording to variable $version, without having to reset $arq.
I'm using [ref] but not sure it's the best way to do so.

I've tryed the following so far.

```
$downloadSource = "\\domain.or.ip\folder"
$version = "0.0.0"
$arq = "file_name_$([ref]$version)`_filename_continuation.zip"

function UpdateVersion {

    (Get-ChildItem -name "$downloadSource\file_name*").Split('_')[2]

    }

$version = UpdateVersion

echo $version
echo $arq
```

Variable $version is being updated correctly.
But $arq is receiving the wrong value:

> "file_name_System.Management.Automation.PSReference`1[System.String]_filename_continuation.zip"

I tried changing $arq as follows

```
$arq = "file_name_" + $(($versaoEsperada).value) + "`_filename_continuation.zip"
```

But the same wrong value is shown.

Would you guys help me, please?
Thanks

Comment: What made you think `[ref]` was needed? Have you tried without it? Try `$arq = "file_name_${version}_filename_continuation.zip"`.

Comment: And, why is there a GRAVE ACCENT (backtick) in the filename?

Comment: The `[ref]` doesn't automatically update a previous assignment. If you want to have the var `$arq` get the actual value of `$version` put the assignment below using the function.

Comment: If I do not use [ref] var $arq won't update at the last echo.
When I use "file_name_${version}_filename_continuation.zip" it results in "file_name_0.0.0_filename_continuation.zip".
If function UpdateVersion returns "5.5.5", I wanted $arq to be "file_name_5.5.5_filename_continuation.zip" without having to reassign it.

Comment: My problem is that [ref] is not updating var $arq either, so it might not be the best approach, as you guys noted.